# Is it possible to pass an implicit to a PartialFunction?

Tags: scala

I have a PartialFunction like this:

```
  val expectNumber: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case i if isNumberChar(chars(i)) =>
      var j = i
      while (j < max && isNumberChar(chars(j)))
        j += 1
      tokenspace.add(JsonToken(Number, i, j))
      j
  }
```

I'd like to access an implicit value within this PF, like this perhaps:

```
  val expectNumber: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case i if isNumberChar(chars(i)) =>
      val thing = implicitly[String]
      var j = i
      while (j < max && isNumberChar(chars(j)))
        j += 1
      tokenspace.add(JsonToken(Number, i, j))
      j
  }
```

Or by any other means of passing in an implicit.  The code above issues a compile error saying it can't find the implicit.  I'm not familiar how (if?) an implicit parameter can be passed into a PartialFunction.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make `expectNumber` a `def` and pass the implicit via it

```
def expectNumber(implicit ev: String): PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
    case i if isNumberChar(chars(i)) =>
      val thing = implicitly[String]
      var j = i
      while (j < max && isNumberChar(chars(j)))
        j += 1
      tokenspace.add(JsonToken(Number, i, j))
      j
  }
```

Comment: You have the implicit. just make `val thing = ev`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Just keeping it there to show that it still comes via implicit.